# gRPC Net6 Client load balancing & SRV record DNS config

Tags: c#, grpc

My service is hosted under IIS (https) and JWT is used for authentication/authorization.
The IT person configured an SRV record DNS but I'm not sure he did it correctly.
I'm getting the following error:

```
Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error getting DNS hosts for address '_http._tcp.grpcpocclientsideloadbalancing.400dev.rsvzinasti.be'. SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
```

The DNS config: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hYRY.png)

Using nslookup returns the correct addresses: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTjB3.png)

My code looks like this:

```cs
var credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((c, m) =>
{
    m.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetStsClaim());
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

var clientHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
clientHandler.UseProxy = false;

var handler = new SubdirectoryHandler(clientHandler, "/TestGrpc");
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("dns:///_http._tcp.grpcpocclientsideloadbalancing.400dev.rsvzinasti.be",
    new GrpcChannelOptions 
    {
        HttpHandler = handler,
        Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(ChannelCredentials.SecureSsl, credentials),
        ServiceConfig = new ServiceConfig
        {
            LoadBalancingConfigs = { new RoundRobinConfig() }
        }
    });
var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

var request = new HelloRequest();
request.Name = "test";

var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(request);
```

Calling `Dns.GetHostAddresses("dns://_http._tcp.grpcpocclientsideloadbalancing.400dev.rsvzinasti.be")` throws
'No such host is known.'

Could you help me find what is wrong with my config ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd try resolving the DNS address with some popular command line tool (e.g. `nslookup`) first and see what comes back (the address should resolve to 1-N IP addresses. This itself should probably be enough to debug what's wrong with the DNS settings.

Comment: @JanTattermusch Thanks for your input. Nslookup is working. I updated the question with the result.